# What's the difference between 'Commit ID' and 'SHA1 Hash' in GIT?

Tags: git, cryptography

I've been working on GIT for quite sometime now.

However, I could not find difference between 'Commit Id' and 'SHA1 - hash value'

What is the difference between 'Commit ID' and 'SHA1'?  Any simple explanation with an example would be nice

Comment: it's the same thing, only the id can be shorter than the full SHA1 (as long as it uniquely identifies the commit)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The commit ID is always exactly the SHA1 of the commit; in most contexts, you can specify an unambiguous prefix of the commit ID as an equivalent reference to the commit.

Answer (score 23):

Commit ID is what identifies a commit. Sometimes, you will see the shorthand version which is just the first seven characters of the actual commit ID versus the full hash.

Consider the following example:

```
[master 42e2e5a] Added a new readme file to illustrate commit IDs.
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 myreadme
```

Notice it is showing the shorthand version of the commit ID. Because the actual commit ID is forty hexadecimal characters that specify a 160-bit SHA-1 hash.

---

### Example

**Full commit ID**

```
git show -s --format=%H
```

**Result**

```
42e2e5af9d49de268cd1fda3587788da4ace418a
```

**Shorthand version**

```
git show -s --format=%h
```

**Result**

```
42e2e5a
```

But notice they are the same.

Comment: Or what is known as content addressable. Some other merkle tree implementations, like ZFS, use addresses as references instead of just the content.

Answer (score 6):

I've read the answers provided before and I think there's a little thing to add to them. A revision always *points* to a sha1 (it doesn't actually point, a revision is *identified* by its sha1 ID but bear with me) but objects in git's DB can be: revisions, trees, blobs, etc and they are all identified by sha1 IDs. So a revision implies using a sha1 ID (to identify it... but there are other sha1 IDs used in a revision like for parents, tree object) but a sha1 ID doesn't necessarily mean it's a revision.