# Git: Merge Specific File from Specific Commit

Tags: git, github

I have one version of a file at commit "`#abc123`" and the current version of the same file locally.

I want to MERGE, NOT REVERT, the two versions for only this file.

I read about some workarounds using "`git cherry pick`", but nothing direct.
Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: See my technique here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361293/341994

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Merge only single file from master into current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916006/git-merge-only-single-file-from-master-into-current-branch)

Comment: Why not [`git merge-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13711776/7976758

Comment: @phd Could work, but requires a base file that might not exist. That was the situation my approach was dealing with.

Comment: @matt Maybe, but I'm kind of newbie with git, so this solution seems a little complicated to me. I did what VonC suggested and it worked very fine. Any way, thank you for your availability. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

- make sure the current version of that file is committed.
- switch to a new branch from the current commit:

  ```
    git switch -c tmp
  ```
- restore that one file from the old commit, using [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore):

  ```
    git restore -s abc123 -SW -- aFile
    git restore --source=<tree> --staged --worktree -- <pathspec>

    git commit -m "restore old version of a file
  ```

Meaning: restore `aFile` content from commit `abc123` -- the source --, and apply that content both to the index/cache (`--staged`), and the working tree -- where files are checked out:  `--worktree`)

- finally I can merge two commits, which will merge only that one file

  ```
    git switch main (or master)
    git merge tmp
  ```

Comment: Would be great to explain used symbols like abc123.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt `abc123` comes from the question, where it is referenced as a commit SHA1 (the shorthand form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764118/6309)

Comment: basiscally the parameter -s describes a source, and i think it could be any rev-description, like branch or tag.

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt Correct. I have added a link to the documentation as well as a clear explanation of each parameters used in the `git restore` command.